# Getting A Correlation Column Based on Two Columns with A List Value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scipy, statistics

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]], 
                   'B': [[17, 18, 12], [21, 22, 13]]})
df

          A               B
0   [10, 11, 12]    [17, 18, 12]
1   [13, 14, 15]    [21, 22, 13]
```

Now I want to create a new column `Correlation` based on the `A` and `B` columns using `scipy.stats.pearsonr` method. I'm trying this:

```
# Creating a function for correlation
def correlation(row):
    correlation, p_value = stats.pearsonr(row['A'], row['B'])
    return correlation

# Applying the function
df['Correlation'] = df.apply(correlation, axis = 1)
df

          A               B         Correlation
0   [10, 11, 12]    [17, 18, 12]    -0.777714
1   [13, 14, 15]    [21, 22, 13]    -0.810885
```

If I have too many columns, the above script would not the ideal. I am thinking if I can directly use `stats.pearsonr` in `lambda` to get the same result?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you want `df.apply(lambda row: stats.pearsonr(row['A'], row['B'])[0], axis = 1)`? and what do you mean by *If I have too many columns, the above script would not the ideal*?

Comment: @Ben.T: Yeah, that's slicing ```[0]```. I completely forgot. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend use `zip` with for loop

```
df['out'] = [stats.pearsonr(x, y)[0] for x, y in zip(df.A, df.B)]
df
Out[163]: 
              A             B       out
0  [10, 11, 12]  [17, 18, 12] -0.777714
1  [13, 14, 15]  [21, 22, 13] -0.810885
```